# Как работает P2P соединение через Wi-Fi Direct?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Нужно написать приложение, которое соединит пользователей из любой точки мира посредством сети интернет. Возможно ли это через P2P с Wi-Fi Direct, который предлагает Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я знаю p2p wifi direct network это сеть которая организовывается между устройствами в определенном радиусе (как блютус) без участия интернет подключения.